# RAII with array of COM objects

Tags: c++, com, raii

### Problem:

In COM you occasionally find functions with signatures like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetColorContexts( 
        UINT cCount,
        IWICColorContext **ppIColorContexts,
        UINT *pcActualCount)
```

The problem this presents for me is that `ppIColorContexts` must be an [initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) array of `IWICColorContext *`. I have tried referencing the first element of a `Vector` of `ATL::CComPtr<IWICColorContext>` with no such luck it won't trigger the `()` operator so it complains about a type mismatch.

### Attempted solutions:

- `vector<ATL::CComPtr<IWICColorContext>>` failed due to type mismatch, <strike>as noted in the comments this has other issues as `CComPtr` overloads `operator &` which breaks STL containers.</strike> It seems that this was [fixed in C++11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) and was included in the STL in VC2010
- `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL` works but still means I'm manually managing the lifetime of the COM objects which is something I'd like to get away from.

### Unattempted solutions:

- Custom data structure - this is likely what I'll have to do if there is not a more elegant solution, but at least it would allow me to take advantage of destruction semantics properly.
- Attach a `CComPtr` after this call - I dislike this solution because it leaves me with a period of execution where the resource may not get released if something goes wrong.
- `std::unique_ptr<IWICColorContext[]>` with a custom deleter - I have yet to fully explore this possibility but it would ensure that the COM objects would always get released.

Comment: It wants an array, just pass a plain old array.  Any wrapping with smart pointers has to be done after the call.

Comment: I think you want something like this: `vector<CAdapt<CComPtr<IWICColorContext> > > vec; GetColorContexts(vec.size(), &vec[0].m_T, ...);`. `CComPtr` cannot be placed into STL containers directly, because it overloads `operator&` which violates container requirements. That's why `CAdapt` was invented.

Comment: @HansPassant I was hoping to avoid that but if that is what I must needs do it is what I must needs do... still I was hoping to avoid `new`

Comment: @HansPassant what about a `std::unique_ptr<IWICColorContext[]>` with a custom deleter? Still not ideal... but it should always be released.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that was [fixed in C++11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) and the fix was included in the TR1 release in VC2010

Comment: In this case, what is this "type mismatch" of which you speak? Exactly what code did you try, and exactly what error message did you get for it?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I wasn't using the access to the pointer like you're demonstrating (as I don't think that `IWICColorContext*[]` and `ATL::CComPtr<IWICColorContext>[]` are going to access the same) I could be wrong but it would seem like making the assumption that the two different array types will access the same is a bit dangerous.

Comment: It so happens that the size of `CComPtr` is exactly the same as the size of the raw pointer it wraps as its only data member. `&vec[0]` (where `vec` is a `vector<CComPtr<...> >`) should work in practice, though yes, technically, it's cheating (specifically, an undefined-behavior-prone sin known as "type punning"). But then, you can't use COM and not cheat: `QueryInterface(..., (void**)&p)` is technically illegal, too, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Ultimately the solution was described by igor tandetnik in the comments above:</strike>

Basically in VC2010+ `ATL::CComPtr` has a `sizeof` that is the same as the pointer they represent (e.g. `sizeof(ATL::CComPtr<IWICColorContext>) == sizeof(IWICColorContext*)`), as best I can tell this is because they have no virtual functions and thus need no vTable. This is however ***highly dangerous*** as it's relying on a compiler implementation detail. Thus the following works:

```
std::vector<ATL::CComPtr<IWICColorContext> > > vec(5);
// CComPtrs are created and initialized here
GetColorContexts(vec.size(), &vec[0].m_T, ...);
```

Mark brought up a very good point that the solution above was completely dependent on compiler implementation which is dangerous. However the solution of only attaching `ATL::CComPtr` after the `GetColorContexts` call was not palattable either as it would not have been exception safe.

Ultimately my solution (tested this morning) is to create a `vector<IWICColorContext*>` temporarily from the `vector<CComPtr<IWICColorContext>>` this temporary `vector` does not increment the ref count and allows me to maintain exception safety.

Comment: You're relying an awful lot on the internals of the CComPtr object here. That's dangerous, especially if it works (today...)

Comment: @MarkRansom I've fixed my answer based on your answer

Answer (score 2):

I would do it by passing a vector of raw pointers to the function, then copying to another vector of `CComPtr`.

```
std::vector<IWICColorContext *> vec(5, NULL);
UINT nActualCount = 0;
GetColorContexts(vec.size(), &vec[0], &nActualCount);
std::vector<CComPtr<IWICColorContext> > results(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + nActualCount);
```

The only unfortunate part is that the `CComPtr` constructor performs an `AddRef` so you must do a corresponding `Release` on the raw pointers before they're lost.

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    if (*it != NULL)
        (*it)->Release();
vec.clear();
```

Comment: While it wouldn't be the most efficient thing to do... I could flip this on its head and create a `std::vector<IWICColorContext*>` from the `vector<CComPtr>` this would not create reference issues and since the number of contexts is small per image anyway it wouldn't be a drain.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need something like that:

```
long lSize = 0;
ptr->GetColorContexts(cCount, NULL, &lSize);//return required amount of contexts
IWICColorContext** ppColorContexts = NULL;
ppColorContexts = new IWICColorContext*[lSize];
ptr->GetColorContexts(cCount, ppColorContexts, &lSize);
//use something to wrap received raw interfaces with CComPtr - 
//for example use for loop to pass them to new container,
//which stores CComPtr<IWICColorContext>
```